# Spritebatch drawing in wrong position

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, spritebatch

Why is my sprite drawing to the top left corner when my wizardPos variable clearly puts it at the middle of the screen?

```
//in load content
wizardPos = new Vector2(graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth /2, 700);
wizardChar = new Characters.Wizard(this, spriteBatch, wizardPos, wizardWalk1);


//in Draw method

 this.spriteBatch.Draw(tempWizard, wizardPos, null, Color.White, 0f, wizardPos, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
```

[image: Wizard should be drawing in red rectangle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.spriteBatch.Draw(tempWizard, wizardPos, null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
```

The `position` of your sprite is actually the position of the `origin` of your sprite. So when you set the `origin` to `wizardPos`, the `origin` is set relative to the sprite - not the screen. So setting the `origin` and `position` to the same value effectively cancel each other out.

The `origin` will usually be somewhere within the bounds of your sprite since it is used to calculate things like rotation as well

Comment: Thank you Beno! Worked perfectly. I didn't understand how origin worked exactly. Appreciate it.